# Google Play Licensing Library issue with Lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lvl

I use the code for license check from this page:

[How to license my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452332/how-to-license-my-android-application)

and want make it also working for Lollipop. The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78505) of the Google Play Licensing Library. The issue is assigned and it will be fixed in the future, in the mean time if you want to use the library also with Lollipop there is a workaround:

In LicenseChecker.java change from this:

```
boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(new Intent(new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U="))),
                                          this, // ServiceConnection.
                                          Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

to this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")));
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(serviceIntent),
                                          this, // ServiceConnection.
                                          Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: I'm using the newest library jar file (all google services - I also use analytics)

Comment: I don't think License Verification Library is inside Google Play Services. Where do you find this info? You should have an external project called play_licensing or something like this

Comment: oh sry that's true • how can I modify it now?

Comment: Open LicenseChecker.java inside the _Google Play License Library_ project and change the code as showed in the answer.