# Can not import libraries for Google Play Licensing in an Activity

Tags: java, android

I followed the answer in this question:

- [How to license my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452332/how-to-license-my-android-application][1])

But I can not import the following libraries inside LicenseCheck.java:

```
import com.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;
```

and because that, there is some errors in that activity.

Also, I downloaded the Google Play Licensing library. But the problem still there.

**The import statements (above) are in the gray color.**

Answer (score 0):

I followed setup guide http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html and it works!

1. Installed/Updated Google Play Services, and Google Repository from SDK Manager
2. Added dependency in build.gradle: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
3. Updated AndroidManifest.xml with

Comment: Do you have any other solution?! Thanks for helping me.